# Add all nodes of a n-ary tree to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, tree

What is the best way to add all nodes of a given tree to an `ArrayList`?

Should I pass ArrayList as parameter in the recursive method?

I am trying to do it for a while now, my code doesn't compile, please help.

```
ArrayList<NodoN<T>> postOrder(boolean ignorarRaiz, ArrayList<T> lista){

        for (int i = 0; i < nodos.size(); i++) {
            ret = ret + nodos.get(i).postOrder(false, lista);
        }

        if (!ingnorarRaiz) {
            lista.add(dato);
        }

        return dato;

    }
```

Comment: Please add what error do you have when you're compiling.

Comment: What compilation error do you get, and on what line?

Comment: Can you also specify what java version you want to use cause this would be easy with streams in java 8 and above.

Comment: It might also be of value to see how your node class is defined.

Comment: Spanish is a beautiful language but SO is a global site. I bet you'd have more help if the code you posted here was English based code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your method name It seems that you want to traverse your tree in post-order so I'd try something like:

```
ArrayList<NodoN<T>> postOrder(boolean ignorarRaiz, ArrayList<T> lista){

    for (NodoN<T> nodo: nodos) {            
        nodo.postOrder(false, lista);
    }

    if (!ingnorarRaiz) lista.add(nodo);

    return lista;

}
```

Where the node explorer at each call gets inserted to your list after the sub-trees nodes has been added.